# how to key press 2 keys in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-rc, keypress

Say my shortcut is shift + r. How to press 2 keys in Selenium RC using Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use these methods

```
keyDownNative('10') // VK_SHIFT
keyPressNative('52') // R
keyUpNative('10') // VK_SHIFT
```